# C++ switch case through typeid's

Tags: c++, templates, switch-statement, typeid

I am developing a program which requires multiple type overloads, I am using templates and would like to apply a different process for different types, since having quite a few types it would be quite messy to use if statements, therefore I would want to use switch statements to neaten my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cinttypes>

template<typename T>
T foo(T value)
{
    //if statment works perfectly fine
    if(typeid(T) == typeid(int32_t))
        std::cout << "32 bit integer" << std::endl;
    else if(typeid(T) == typeid(int64_t))
        std::cout << "64 bit integer" << std::endl;
    //...more conditions...//

    //switch statment causes errors
    switch(typeid(T)) //error: switch quantity not an integer
    {
        case typeid(int32_t): //error: could not convert ‘*(const std::type_info*)(& _ZTIi)’ from ‘const std::type_info’ to ‘<type error>’
            std::cout << "32 bit integer" << std::endl;
            //...
            break;
        case typeid(int64_t): //error: could not convert ‘*(const std::type_info*)(& _ZTIl)’ from ‘const std::type_info’ to ‘<type error>’
            std::cout << "64 bit integer" << std::endl;
            //...
            break;
        //...more cases...//
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo<int>(int32_t());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: What's wrong with function overloading?

Comment: you need to show a code illustrating what you mean.

Comment: `std::type_info` isn't a integral or enumeration type. See [switch](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch)

Comment: Ok, does that mean that this won't be possible even if I were to use typeid().name()

Comment: "switch(typeid(T))" is not possible. You can't switch on anything dynamic in C++. You can only switch on constants.

Comment: @nicomp I guess the hope was that e.g. `typeid(int32_t)` could be resolved at compile-time.

Comment: @nicomp Not true, e.g. `switch(rand())`.  The case labels must be constant expressions.

Comment: @Bathsheba or template specialization